# Access REST API as client in c++ with boost, ethernet framing issue

Tags: c++, http, boost-asio

I try to get a JSON from a REST API (blocking is fine for now) using boost::asio::read. The problem I have is that I don't know how to deal if the response consists of multiple ethernet frames. When this is the case and I print the JSON, between the frames there is some "rubbish", I don't know if it is padding or some headers. How do I solve this? How can I know until when I have to read and from where I need to read again? Thanks.

```
    uint16_t port = 80; //TLS later?
    std::string address = this->hostip_ + ":" + std::to_string(port);

    //resolve address
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(hostip_, std::to_string(port));
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    //create socket
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);

    try
    {
        boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not connect to API host";
        return false;
    }

    //form the request
    std::string hostAddress = hostip_ + ":" + std::to_string(port);


    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << "GET " << restURI_ << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request_stream << "Host: " << hostAddress << "\r\n";
    request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    //send the request
    boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    //read the full response
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::system::error_code error;



    while (boost::asio::read(socket, response,boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error));
    
    //convert to string
    boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type buf = response.data();
    const std::string bufferstr(boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf), boost::asio::buffers_begin(buf) + response.size());
```

Comment: If you're connecting via a regular TCP socket, there's no way ethernet frames are visible or relevant. All that stuff is taken care of by the TCP stack. Try logging what exactly is read by (and returned by) each call to `asio::read` before you assume something is going wrong elsewhere.

Comment: OK yeah it's regular TCP...when I look via Wireshark, the unexpected stuff is between the ethernet frames, that's why I assumed it must have to do with that. I will tomorrow post what exactly comes between the expected bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Boost.Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html), Portable HTTP, WebSocket, and network operations using only C++11 and Boost.Asio !